# How does this design differ materially from an existing mesh covered seat frame?

Tags: patent-infringement

The design and accompanying illustration appear very similar to, and derivative of the seat frame used on the Bell UH-1H(and previous models) helicopter developed in the 1960s. While there is an obvious difference in application (helicopter vs. recumbent bicycle) the basic design of the frame, plus the use of tensioned nylon mesh suggests the bicycle seat was adapted from the helicopter seat.
Please see the attached photos:[image: UH-1 seat frame]

Comment: Could you give us the patent number you're talking about?

Comment: Can you rotate the picture correctly?